# Is 7^2015 + 4^2015 divisible by 17? Explain your reasoning and show your work.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Is $7^{2015} + 4^{2015}$ divisible by 17? Explain your reasoning and show your work.

I'm confused on how exactly I would do this. Would I need to use Fermats Theorem?

Comment: Fermat's Theorem is indeed useful here. But one can do without roughly as quickly, maybe more quickly.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Using Fermat's little theorem is the canonical way to reduce this to a manageable size. For a truly by-hand solution, consider $4\cdot7\cdot(7^{2015}+4^{2015})$.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: no it;s not from any contest

Answer (score 2):

Using Fermat's little theorem and the fact that 16 divides 2016, the given expression (mod 17) is equal to $4^{-1}+7^{-1}$ (mod 17) which is $13+5=18=1$ (mod 17); alternatively, $4 \neq -7$ (mod 17) is sufficient to prove that the given expression is not divisible by 17.

Comment: What is the rule that says you can do this? the $4 \ne -7 (\mod 17)$ part

Comment: Also how did you get 2016 when the number is ^2015?

Comment: $a^{2015}=a^{2016}*a^{-1}=a^{-1}$ (mod 17).

Comment: How do you figure out how to do $4^{-1} \mod 17$

Answer (score 2):

> *Would I need to use [Fermat's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) ?*

Not necessarily; for instance, you could simply write $7^2=49=51-2=3\cdot17-2$, along with $(-2)^4=4^2=16=17-1$.

Comment: i will go with Lucian